# Keeping a fullscreen XNA game on top

Tags: windows, fullscreen, xna-4.0, direct3d, multiple-monitors

I have a fullscreen xna game that is supposed to run on a secondary screen if available. It all works fine getting it into fullscreen mode on the secondary screen. However, when i focus a window on the primary screen, the fullscreen application on the secondary screen unfocusses. AlwaysOnTop is not an option here, as this is not a form, but a fullscreen application. How would i go around and tackle this problem?

Comment: By loses focus, do you mean it minimizes itself?

Comment: yes it does! when i click the tray icon, it comes up in fullscreen again.

Comment: This is normal behaviour. I wonder if it's possible to override it. If not - you could just mess with the underlying `Form` to make it look like it is full-screen.

Answer (score 0):

Full screen is usually supposed to only work if it has focus I think. You could always make the application a border less window that is the size of the monitor. So it is still "full screen" without having to have focus. I wrote some code a little while ago to do this and it really isn't that hard to do let me see if i can find it..

```
        WindowPoint = Window.Position;
        WindowPoint.X = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Location.X;
        WindowPoint.Y = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Location.Y;
        Window.Position = WindowPoint;
        Window.IsBorderless = true;

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Width;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Height;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false;           
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

I am sure that there is a better way to do this. I'm still learning myself but this gets the job done. On my computer AllScreens[0] is the second monitor and [1] is the primary monitor. Let me know if this helps. Good luck :)

Comment: Wow just looked at the date on this question XD a little late I guess.